# Correctly retaining listeners on orientation changes

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface, android-orientation

Consider the following scenario:

1. I have an `Activity` with UI elements that launches a `DialogFragment` when clicked
2. The `DialogFragment` has a listener `interface` that the `Activity` provides an implementation of. Say for example, the `Activity` is an image editor and the `DialogFragment` selects a contrast - the dialog would have a `OnContrastChangedListener` that the `Activity` implements
3. The `Activity` has implemented this `interface` to update views in its UI. Continuing the image editor example, the `Activity` implements the `OnContrastChangedListener` to update its preview view - something like this:

   ```
   contrastDialog.setOnContrastChangedListener(new OnContrastChangedListener {
       @Override
       public void OnContrastChanged(int newContrast) {
           getPreviewView().updateWithContrast(newContrast);            
       }
   });
   ```
4. The orientation is changed, and everything is recreated and the listener saved and restored correctly using the methods recommended [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) (listener is saved in a `Fragment` and restored when the lifecycle is restoring state).

The problem is the listener interface now **does not** work. The function `getPreviewView()` is now returning `null` even though when called anywhere else in the `Activity` it returns the correct value

Excuse the poor terminology (my knowledge in compiling and bytecode is limited), but I can grasp what has happened. The interface has been compiled with the `getPreviewView()` version that returned the preview view that was destroyed on the orientation change, and this has since been released / garbage collected / is now `null`.

My question is, is there a way in Java to make the interface compile expecting the values / functions to change - much like the `volatile` keyword in C (I am expecting there isn't)? In that case, what's the best approach for getting around this type of situation? I have considered the following:

- <strike>Create the `DialogFragment` (and its `interface`) in the code that is rerun when the `Activity` is recreated. This is fine for things like `OnClickListeners` for `Buttons` as they are definitely created. But this `DialogFragment` is only created when a button is pressed, so this approach means every dialog for the screen is created each time the `Activity` is - this seems wasteful given they may not even be run</strike>
- <strike>Create all possible `interfaces` for the `Activity` every time and save them in member variables, then use these `interfaces` when the `DialogFragments` are requested to be created by the event. Same comments as above - seems wasteful creating every possible `interface` just in case it is run.</strike>
- Keep some hacky "open dialog state" member variables in the Activity that guide the recreation of the `interfaces`. Hacky and creates a tie between the `Activity` and the `DialogFragment` which isn't great practice.

As you can see, all options involve recreation that is wasteful to some extent - is there a way to reuse the existing `interface` implementation?

**EDIT:** Options 1 and 2 won't work because they need a link to the existing `Dialog`. This is all doable but it is leaning more and more towards the hacked together option of having 'current Dialog' variables, getting the `DialogFragment` with `FragmentManager` when the activity is restarted, casting it appropriately based on the 'current Dialog' variable, recreating the listener. Is there a less messy way?

Comment: Where is `getPreviewView()` implement? Can you show us this method?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: that's just an example. For that example its implementation could simply be `return (PreviewView) findViewById(R.id.preview);` where `PreviewView` is a custom view class and `R.id.preview` is the ID defined in the XML layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `onAttach` `onDetach` method is good and I like using it, sometimes, when I know there will be more developers in the code I don't even cast it blindly, but I do a check like this:

```
if(activity instanceof MyInterface){
   interface = (MyInterface) activity;
} else{
   thrown new RuntimeException("Dear colleague, this fragment was meant to have the activity implementing MyInterface or else a bunch of other stuff won't work, please go back to your code and add the interface");
}
```

but as a different resort, you can also re-set the interface when the fragment is recreated. For example, on the activity `onCreate`

```
if(savedInstanceState != null){
    mDialogFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MyDialogFrag.TAG);
    if(mDialogFrag != null)
       mDialogFrag.setListener(... the interface   ...);
}
```

I know that's also not the best separation of objects, but the fact is that `getPreviewView()` NEEDS the current activity to proper operate, so you NEED to pass this reference again when everybody gets destroyed n rebuilt.

Those are just different ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If the activity will always have the implementation of the interface, would it be possible to set your listener in the DialogFragment's onAttach()? This will ensure that when it is destroyed and recreated, it will have the most up-to-date reference, like:

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    contrastChangedListener = (OnContrastChangedListener)activity;
}

public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    contrastChangedListener = null;

}
```

Comment: That's essentially just option 2 (which is looking like the best possibility). There's a few reasons this answer won't work though (casting activity to a listener: assuming activity implements is a bad assumption to make, what happens if another fragment implements the listener?)